# Missing Parameter for Anonymous Function

Tags: scala, parameters, anonymous

The compiler is complaining about the code below, saying: missing parameter type for expanded function

I'm not sure how to make it happy.  Any ideas?

```
def unwrapMap(m: Map[_, _]) =
  { (vcType: String) =>
    m.map {
      case (k, v) => {
        (k,v)  // echo the map for sample purposes
      }
    }.toMap
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give concrete types to your Map instead of discarding them with '_':

```
  def unwrapMap[A, B](m: Map[A, B]) =
  { (vcType: String) =>
    m.map {
      case (k, v) => {
        (k,v)  // echo the map for sample purposes
      }
    }.toMap
  }
```

That way the compiler can infer the type of the anonymous function created into the method '.map'.